# How to properly write thai/malaysia language characters in xml using php?

Tags: php, xml, thai

I am working on a project where I have to send data to API through xml. Its basically a SOAP based API, its working fine with the English language but when i try to send thai characters it does not work. Thai characters converted to "????...". I am using php for server side scripting. My web page charset is "UTF-8". Can any one help me in fixing this issue.[I have attached an image of code also. PFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3thLR.png)

Comment: You are doing something wrong in your code where you create the XML. Obviously there's no way to tell what exactly with the information given.

Comment: Ok I am editing my question and adding the code